# ooVoo SDK compilation errors in swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk, oovoo

i'm trying to integrate the ova SDK in swift project using an objective c  bridging header in coding it look like it succeed and i can access the SDK classes but when i trying to compile i get a lot of apple mach-o linker warning and errors i will put them below thanks for your helping

the warnings:

```
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(opus_decoder.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(opus_encoder.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(celt_decoder.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(celt_encoder.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(entdec.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(entenc.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(opus.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(repacketizer.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(analysis.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(dec_API.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(enc_API.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(lin2log.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(log2lin.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(celt_lpc.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(quant_bands.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(bands.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(check_control_input.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(mdct.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(celt.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(rate.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(entcode.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(mlp.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(mlp_data.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(modes.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(kiss_fft.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(pitch.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(vq.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(HP_variable_cutoff.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(tables_other.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(control_SNR.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(control_codec.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(decode_frame.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(decode_indices.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(decode_pulses.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(decoder_set_fs.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(encode_frame_FLP.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(encode_indices.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(encode_pulses.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(init_decoder.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(init_encoder.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(resampler.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(stereo_LR_to_MS.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(stereo_MS_to_LR.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(stereo_decode_pred.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(stereo_encode_pred.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(cwrs.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(laplace.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(mathops.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(CNG.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(LP_variable_cutoff.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(tables_LTP.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(tables_NLSF_CB_NB_MB.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(tables_NLSF_CB_WB.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(NLSF_unpack.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(wrappers_FLP.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(PLC.o)
(null): Ignoring debug info with an invalid version (602049001) in /Applications/Development/ooVooSDK-iOS-1.5.0.73/ooVooSDK-iOS.framework/ooVooSDK-iOS(resampler_rom.o)
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::write(char const*, long)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::getline(char*, long, char)", referenced from:
(null): "_AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer", referenced from:
(null): "_AudioConverterNew", referenced from:
(null): "_vDSP_vsdiv", referenced from:
(null): "_vDSP_vsmul", referenced from:
(null): "_vDSP_vclip", referenced from:
(null): "_CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp", referenced from:
(null): "_AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium", referenced from:
(null): "_AVCaptureSessionPresetLow", referenced from:
(null): "_AVMediaTypeAudio", referenced from:
(null): "_AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720", referenced from:
(null): "_AVMediaTypeVideo", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::compare(wchar_t const*) const", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::assign(wchar_t const*)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::append(wchar_t const*)", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for unsigned long long", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for unsigned int", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for unsigned char", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(unsigned long long&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(unsigned int&)", referenced from:
(null): "vtable for std::bad_cast", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::imbue(std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::sync()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::xsgetn(wchar_t*, long)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::underflow()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::pbackfail(int)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::collate<wchar_t>::id", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__get_classname(char const*, bool)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__get_collation_name(char const*)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::operator=(wchar_t)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::regex_error::regex_error(std::__1::regex_constants::error_type)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::operator>>(unsigned int&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::operator>>(unsigned short&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::get()", referenced from:
(null): "_vDSP_vflt16", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__match_any_but_newline<wchar_t>::__exec(std::__1::__state<wchar_t>&) const", referenced from:
(null): "std::__throw_bad_alloc()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::ctype<wchar_t>::id", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::regex_error::~regex_error()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::operator<<(bool)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::basic_streambuf()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::append(wchar_t const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::operator<<(unsigned int)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::locale::name() const", referenced from:
(null): "_AudioOutputUnitStop", referenced from:
(null): "_AudioComponentFindNext", referenced from:
(null): "_AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat", referenced from:
(null): "_AudioUnitInitialize", referenced from:
(null): "_AudioComponentInstanceDispose", referenced from:
(null): "_AudioUnitGetProperty", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::insert(unsigned long, char const*)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::xsputn(wchar_t const*, long)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for float", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(float)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(long long)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::locale::has_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
(null): "std::bad_cast::~bad_cast()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::codecvt<char, char, __mbstate_t>::id", referenced from:
(null): "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
(null): "vtable for std::__1::system_error", referenced from:
(null): "vtable for std::__1::ios_base::failure", referenced from:
(null): "std::logic_error::logic_error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
(null): "std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()", referenced from:
(null): "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
(null): "vtable for std::__1::basic_istream<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >", referenced from:
(null): "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
(null): "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
(null): "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__call_once(unsigned long volatile&, void*, void (*)(void*))", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::~basic_streambuf()", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::bad_cast", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::seekpos(std::__1::fpos<__mbstate_t>, unsigned int)", referenced from:
(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice", referenced from:
(null): "std::nothrow", referenced from:
(null): "___cxa_rethrow", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::out_of_range", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(bool)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::locale::operator==(std::__1::locale const&) const", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::condition_variable::notify_all()", referenced from:
(null): "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(int&)", referenced from:
(null): "vtable for std::__1::__assoc_sub_state", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::push_back(wchar_t)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__shared_count::~__shared_count()", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::__1::future_error", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::future_error::~future_error()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
(null): "operator new(unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr()", referenced from:
(null): "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(char const*)", referenced from:
(null): "std::bad_cast::bad_cast()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::resize(unsigned long, wchar_t)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::overflow(int)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::mutex::unlock()", referenced from:
(null): "std::runtime_error::~runtime_error()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
(null): "_vDSP_vfix16", referenced from:
(null): "vtable for std::length_error", referenced from:
(null): "non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__assoc_sub_state::__sub_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(unsigned short&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::pbackfail(int)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::thread::join()", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::__1::__assoc_sub_state", referenced from:
(null): "_AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::future_category()", referenced from:
(null): "std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::runtime_error", referenced from:
(null): "std::bad_exception::~bad_exception()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::chrono::steady_clock::now()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned long)", referenced from:
(null): "_AudioUnitSetProperty", referenced from:
(null): "std::logic_error::logic_error(std::logic_error const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__shared_count::__release_shared()", referenced from:
(null): "std::bad_cast::what() const", referenced from:
(null): "_AudioComponentInstanceNew", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::bad_alloc", referenced from:
(null): "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
(null): "std::bad_exception::what() const", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::__init(wchar_t const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)", referenced from:
(null): "___cxa_get_exception_ptr", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_out_of_range() const", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__add_shared()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::push_back(char)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::insert(std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*>, char)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
(null): "non-virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream()", referenced from:
(null): "std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::condition_variable::notify_one()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::future<void>::~future()", referenced from:
(null): "_AudioOutputUnitStart", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::future_error::future_error(std::__1::error_code)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::bad_exception", referenced from:
(null): "std::bad_alloc::what() const", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
(null): "std::exception::what() const", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for int", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::exception", referenced from:
(null): "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::__grow_by(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::__1::__shared_weak_count", referenced from:
(null): "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::__thread_struct::~__thread_struct()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::locale::classic()", referenced from:
(null): "std::current_exception()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__grow_by(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
(null): "std::exception_ptr::exception_ptr(std::exception_ptr const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::ios_base::imbue(std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::locale::locale(std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::locale::operator=(std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
(null): "std::exception::~exception()", referenced from:
(null): "std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::condition_variable::~condition_variable()", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> > const&)", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::numpunct<char>::id", referenced from:
(null): "___cxa_allocate_exception", referenced from:
(null): "typeinfo for std::length_error", referenced from:
(null): "vtable for std::__1::bad_weak_ptr", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::bad_weak_ptr::~bad_weak_ptr()", referenced from:
(null): "std::logic_error::what() const", referenced from:
(null): "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
(null): "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long)", referenced from:
(null): "___cxa_throw", referenced from:
Showing first 200 errors only
```

thanks again:)

Comment: Please add some of the code which causes this!

Comment: i only import the oovoo framework, add a bridging header with this line:
#import <ooVooSDK-iOS/ooVooSDK-iOS.h>
and try to add this line to the viewdidload method in the main view controller just for checking:
var xcd:ooVooVideoView = ooVooVideoView()

Comment: How did u solve this isssue?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed these errors by adding the framework `libc++.tbd` in build phases tab.

Hope this will help others.