# ooVoo within iOS and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oovoo

Has anyone had success in using ooVoo within Swift? I have installed ooVooSDK-iOS via cocoapods and followed documentation, but keep running into issues while compiling and linking

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ooVooController", referenced from:
__TMaCSo15ooVooController in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I did try every architecture with no success. The document does says the framework supports --> ooVooSDK-iOS: the ooVoo SDK library binary supports armv7, armv7s, arm64 and i386/x86_64 (for simulators) platforms.

Comment: Did you open the xcproj or the xcworkspace?

Comment: I opend  xcworkspace

Comment: I've solved this issue. You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35843284/756941

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work using the following pod : ooVooSDK2